# Extending an object and overriding a procedure without being deferred in Fortran

Tags: oop, fortran, polymorphism, intel-fortran

I have a code with lots of different features and methods. Some methods are all for the same feature, i.e. only one among a selection can be selected.

Furthermore, depending on a feature I might need to do modify subroutines elsewhere. So in a loop in routine `inject` I might have a small if statement asking if I have used feature `A`, then do a few extra operations. 
This is very frustating since different features seems to be connected with others routines very arbirarirly, and can be difficult to maintain.

I have decided to do following to avoid this:

I define an object `t_inject` with the purpose to execture routine `inject`.  I rewrite my routine `inject` such that it contains only the code that is common for all different scenarios.

```
 type t_inject 


 contains 

 procedure,nopass :: inject => inject_default
 end type
```

Now I have another object to handle my feature `A` in case it is selected.

```
 type,extends(t_inject) :: t_inject_a


 contains 

 procedure, nopass :: inject => inject_a
 end type
```

My subroutines inject_a and inject have same interface. E.g.

```
 subroutine inject_a( part ) 
  type(t_part) , intent(inout) :: part % an external data type 
 call inject(part) 
 ! do the extra bit of stuff you need to do

 end subroutine 

 subroutine inject( part) 
   type(t_part) , intent(inout) :: part % an external data type 

  ! carry out the default stuff 
 end subroutine
```

Now in my main program

```
class(t_inject) :: inj 

allocate(inj :: t_inject_a) 

call inj% inject ( part)
```

Is that the way you would do it and is it valid?
I initially thought of doing an abstract declared type with a `deferred` inject procedure  where I then could extent. 
But for a very trivial problem I might not need that - I am also wondering whether my call `call inj% inject(part)` is sufficient for the compiler to know to where to go. Sometimes I see codes which need the `class is` condition before making the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think three points should be modified:

- The type-bound procedures need to refer to actual procedure names (via `=>`). So, I have changed the name of a module procedure `inject()` to `inject_default()`. (But please see test2.f90 also).
- We need to attach `allocatable` to a class variable (e.g., `inj2`) to allocate it with a concrete type (e.g., `t_inject_a`).
- In the `allocate` statement, the name of a concrete type should appear before `::`, such that `allocate( t_inject_a :: inj2 )`.

The modified code may look like this:

```
!! test.f90
module test_mod
    implicit none

    type t_inject 
    contains 
        procedure, nopass :: inject => inject_default
    endtype

    type, extends(t_inject) :: t_inject_a
    contains 
        procedure, nopass :: inject => inject_a
    endtype

    type t_part    !! some other type
        integer :: x = 100, y = 200
    endtype

contains
    subroutine inject_default( part )
        type(t_part), intent(inout) :: part

        print *, "x = ", part % x
    endsubroutine

    subroutine inject_a( part ) 
        type(t_part), intent(inout) :: part

        call inject_default( part )
        print *, "y = ", part % y
    endsubroutine 
end

program main
    use test_mod
    implicit none
    class( t_inject ), allocatable :: inj1, inj2
    type( t_part ) :: part

    !! Polymorphic allocation with concrete types.
    allocate( t_inject   :: inj1 )
    allocate( t_inject_a :: inj2 )

    print *, "inj1:"
    call inj1 % inject( part )

    print *, "inj2:"
    call inj2 % inject( part )
end
```

"gfortran-8 test.90 && ./a.out" gives

```
 inj1:
 x =          100
 inj2:
 x =          100
 y =          200
```

---

We can also use a module procedure `inject()` (rather than  `inject_default()`) by using `procedure, nopass :: inject`, for example:

```
!! test2.f90
module test_mod
    implicit none

    type t_inject 
    contains 
        procedure, nopass :: inject
        ! procedure, nopass :: inject => inject  !! this also works
    endtype

    type, extends(t_inject) :: t_inject_a
    contains 
        procedure, nopass :: inject => inject_a
    endtype

    type t_part    !! some other type
        integer :: x = 100, y = 200
    endtype

contains
    subroutine inject( part )
        type(t_part), intent(inout) :: part

        print *, "x = ", part % x
    endsubroutine

    subroutine inject_a( part ) 
        type(t_part), intent(inout) :: part

        call inject( part )
        print *, "y = ", part % y
    endsubroutine 
end

!! The remaining part (and the result) is the same...
```

---

In addition, one can also separate actual procedures like `inject()` in a different file and `use` them to define new types like `t_inject` (see `mylib.f90` and `test3.f90` below). This might be useful to reuse routines in some library file.

```
!! mylib.f90
module mylib
    implicit none

    type t_part    !! some other type
        integer :: x = 100, y = 200
    endtype

contains

    subroutine inject( part )
        type(t_part), intent(inout) :: part

        print *, "x = ", part % x
    end
    subroutine inject_a( part ) 
        type(t_part), intent(inout) :: part

        call inject( part )
        print *, "y = ", part % y
    end
end

!! test3.f90
module test_mod
    use mylib
    implicit none

    type t_inject 
    contains 
        procedure, nopass :: inject
    endtype

    type, extends(t_inject) :: t_inject_a
    contains 
        procedure, nopass :: inject => inject_a
    endtype
end

!! The main program is the same as test.f90.
!! compile: gfortran-8 mylib.f90 test3.f90
```

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask if an abstract declared type, with a corresponding deferred procedure, only becomes sensible to use if you are defining you "deferred" procedure in a different file part of a declared type that has been extended from the abstract type. I just wondered when the latter becomes useful to use

Comment: (I may be misunderstanding your question but anyway...) Even if the actual procedures are given in some different file, we can define a new type by a `use` statement (please see the updated part above, mylib.f90 and test3.f90). But in other situations, deferred bindings may also be useful...

Comment: Because I guess the topic is pretty broad, it might be useful to post a related question in some forum (rather than Q/A sites like here) for more discussion, like [comp.lang.fortran](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.fortran) (e.g. [a recent thread on OO](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.fortran/Zw6u0kI2pFQ/2GHMS5J3AwAJ)) or reddit(?) etc